# Strip nulls from message in syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng

I need to strip NULL's from the incoming message so I can forward it back out to another host. Syslog-ng does not forward messages properly that have any nulls in it. I've tried the following but cannot figure out how to target the NULL in the strings. With the below I still see the nulls in my local log and the remote system never see's the messages with nulls in it *(not all messages have nulls and the ones that don't have nulls forward properly).*

```
source s_ise {
  udp(port(522));
};

destination d_ise {
  file("/var/log/ise.log");
  udp("myhost.example" port(516) spoof_source(no));
};

rewrite r_ise {
  # remove nulls, or it won't forward properly
  subst("\x00", "", type("string"), value("MESSAGE"), flags(substring, global));
};

log {
  source(s_ise);
  filter(f_ise_aaa);
  rewrite(r_ise);
  destination(d_ise);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULLs are considered as string terminators.

Fortunately, the UDP source does not rely on line endings (newline characters or NULLs), so you can remove all unnecessary 0 bytes before parsing, for example:

```
source s_ise {
  udp(port(522) flags(no-parse));
};

rewrite r_remove_nulls {
  subst('\x00', '', value("MESSAGE"), type(pcre), flags(global)); # single quotes!
};

parser p_syslog {
  syslog-parser();
};

destination d_ise {
  file("/var/log/ise.log");
  udp("myhost.example" port(516) spoof_source(no));
};

log {
  source(s_ise);
  rewrite(r_remove_nulls);
  parser(p_syslog);

  filter(f_ise_aaa);
  destination(d_ise);
};
```

---

Alternatively, you can keep NULL bytes, but in that case, you should not use syslog-ng config objects that treat the message as strings (for example, parsers, string-based rewrite rules, string filters, etc).

Comment: Interesting. I kept using double quotes in my rewrite because the docs said single quotes don't get parsed. I've tried what you said and I can see the nulls are stripped from my local log now! however, Its not forwarding to the remote host still... I'm debugging it now.

Comment: Yeah, when using double quotes, \ is an escape character interpreted by syslog-ng. Single quotes make sure that \ is meant for the PCRE engine, not for syslog-ng.

Comment: I got it to work finally. Your solution helped, but I ultimately also had to change the destination to use TCP() instead of UDP() (since i don't need to spoof this is fine). I'm not sure why, the messages are about 2k in size and our network is using jumbo frames (8192). At least it works....